# Powershell command Trouble with 'new-item'

Tags: python, powershell

Currently I'm working through a python book where I'm trying to create a skeleton project directory and there's a command that is as follows: `new–item –type file tests/__init__.py`,[There was a command before that worked fine that was: `new-item -type file NAME/__init__.py`] and I keep getting an error. The error is as follows:

```
New-Item : Could not find a part of the path

'C:\Users\sonny\desktop\projects\skeleton\tests\__init__.py'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Item -type file tests/__init__.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\sonny\...sts\__init__.py:String) [New-Item], DirectoryNotFoundExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Any feedback is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The syntanx is wrong. Are you literally trying to make a file named 'tests/init.py'? Powershell recognizes the forward slash as a directory `/`. It was done like that for familiarity for linux users and easy transition. So you're telling it to create the file in a directory that doesn't exist. So: `New-Item -Type File -Name '_init_.py'` will create that file in that current directory, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Type this in, in your powershell: `Help New-Item`.  A quick summary: parameters enclosed in brackets that are by themselves are Mandatory parameters. Meaning, you'd have to specify something to it for it to run. `[ LogName]` but, if its followed by the value in the brackets, it's optional. `[ LogName <string>]` compared to`[ LogName ] <string>`.

Comment: They're also considered positional but, as long as you provide the parameter name, that parameter can be placed anywhere on the cmdlet syntax. `Get-EventLog -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) -Newest 10 -EntryType Error -LogName Application`. If you look at the help file for `Get-EventLog`, you'll notice everything I specified is out of order. It works because, I've specified the parameter name even tho `LogName` is positional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-Force` switch so it creates the folder `Tests` before creating the py file.

`New-Item –type file tests/__init__.py -Force`

Answer (score 1):

you first have to create the path `tests` if it does not exist. thereafter you can create files in that directory.

```
$skeletonPath = 'C:\Users\sonny\desktop\projects\skeleton'
$testsPathName = 'tests'
$testsPath = Join-Path -Path $skeletonPath -ChildPath $testsPathName
$initFilePath = Join-Path -Path $testsPath -ChildPath '__init__.py'

if(-not(Test-Path -Path $testsPahth)) {
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path $skeletonPath -Name $testsPathName
}

New-Item -Type File -Path $initFilePath
```